# Comparing two dependent intra-class correlations (ICCs)

Tags: bootstrap, reliability, intraclass-correlation

We are measuring two waves from a biological signal.  As an example consider the ECG $P$ wave and $T$ wave.  From a single trace, the amplitude of both of these waves is measured.  We want to compare the inter-session reliability of the two waves; doing a second measurement a week later.  So in this example we have $P_1$, $P_2$, $T_1$ and $T_2$.  We expect, and have found, correlations between ($P_1$, $P_2$) ($P_1$, $T_1$) and all of the combinations.  $ICC_{2,1}$ for the $P$ wave ($P_1$, $P_2$) was $0.8$ and for the $T$ wave was $0.6$.  Confidence intervals for each ICC can be computed by bootstrap but how can we compare the test-retest reliabilities of the two waves?

Comment: Do $P_1$, $P_2$, $T_1$ and $T_2$ all refer to vectors of *exchangeable* values (exchangeable within a vector)? Or is there, for example, some sensible a priori pairing between the values in $P_1$ and $T_1$, so that the ordering of the values in each vector is *not* arbitrary?

Answer (score 1):

Lu L, Shara NM. Reliability analysis: calculate and compare intra-class correlation coefficients (ICC) in SAS. Northeast SAS Users Group; 2007.
illustrate a method to compare 2 independent ICCs
In a similar fashion ou could calculate bootstrapped ICCs differences of paired observations and use a one sample t test.
This can easily be implemented in R using the boot and ICC packages
Also try reading [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Yun-Hee_Choi/publication/230613150_Confidence_Interval_Estimation_for_a_Difference_Between_Two_Dependent_Intraclass_Correlation_Coefficients_With_Variable_2_Class_Sizes/links/09e41502199ea26990000000/Confidence-Interval-Estimation-for-a-Difference-Between-Two-Dependent-Intraclass-Correlation-Coefficients-With-Variable-2-Class-Sizes.pdf).